# How should add static option to dynamic dropdown in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting dropdown with list of services but I need to add one more option static like "Choose Service" in the dynamic dropdown list.

This is my code:

```
if (data[0]) {
    $('#SelectedServiceIds').html("");
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        $('#SelectedServiceIds').append(
                 $("<option></option>").attr("value", value.ServiceID).text(value.ServiceName)); 
    });
}
```

And this is my div:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group select-services">

        <select class="form-control"  name="SelectedServiceIds" id="SelectedServiceIds" placeholder="Choose Service">
            <option>Choose Service</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your if block replace this line $('#SelectedServiceIds').html(""); with $('#SelectedServiceIds').html("<option value="">Choose Service</option>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go, simply add this option back before the loop (and you may remove it from the html too)

```
if (data[0]) {
  //Remove all options
  $("#SelectedServiceIds").html("");

  //Add the static option
  $("#SelectedServiceIds").append(
    $("<option></option>").attr("value", -1).text("Choose Service")
  );

  //Add the dynamic options
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $("#SelectedServiceIds").append(
      $("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", value.ServiceID)
        .text(value.ServiceName)
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: It is coming  at end of dropdown but i need that value at first

Comment: @ArunRaju, then just add it before the loop. See my updated code.

Comment: @ArunRaju, I see that you have cast no votes at all in your profile, you may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data[0]) {
                $('#SelectedServiceIds').html("");
$('#SelectedServiceIds').append('<option value="0" selected="selected">Choose Service</option>');
                 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                 $('#SelectedServiceIds').append(
                 $("<option></option>").attr("value", value.ServiceID).text(value.ServiceName));
                            });

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

can prepend text as below

```
if (data[0]) {
                $('#SelectedServiceIds').html("");

                 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                 $('#SelectedServiceIds').append(
                 $("<option></option>").attr("value", value.ServiceID).text(value.ServiceName));
                            });

$("#SelectedServiceIds").prepend($("<option></option>").attr("value", -1).text("Choose Service").attr("selected",true));

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty option before the begning of the loop like this :

```
if (data[0]) {
    $('#SelectedServiceIds').html("<option value=''>Choose Service</option>");
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        $('#SelectedServiceIds').append(
            $("<option></option>").attr("value", value.ServiceID).text(value.ServiceName));
    });

}
```